# How can I rename files with Cyrillic characters, replacing the Cyrillic alphabet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, rename, cyrillic

I have a folder containing 100+ mp3 files.

they respect this pattern: '`000. MSK_NAME.mp3`'

I have a code to rename all my files, and it's working almost fine. 
Besides the fact I'm facing some trouble when the filename has some Cyrillic chars.

> For example:

**/musics:**

```
'''
011. ?????? - ? ?? ???? ??? ???? (Dima Flash.mp3
012. ?????? feat. ?????? ??????? - ???????? (DJ Shtopor & DJ Oleg Petroff Remix).mp3
018. MarQ Markuz - ?????? (DJ A.G. RnDeep Remix).mp3
026. Serebro - ?????????? (DJ Denis Rublev & DJ Anton Remix).mp3
027. Samoel feat. ?????? - ????????????? ????? (Oleg Perets & Alexey Galin Remix) .mp3
029. 5sta Family - ????? (Tony Sky Sax Remix) .mp3
030. ???? ???? - ????? ????? (Dj Jurbas Nu-Disco Mix ).mp3
036. Quest Pistols - ????? ????? (DJ Denis Rublev & DJ Timur Remix).mp3
037. Serebro - ?????????? (Mickey Martini & Alexx Slam Remix).mp3
041. ??? - ???? ? ???? (Tony Sky Remix).mp3
'''
```

**renamer.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

folder = "C:\\users\\myuser\\desktop\\musics"

for item in os.listdir(folder):
    item2 = item[5:]
    path = folder + "\\" + item
    try:
        renamed = folder  + "\\" + item2
        os.rename(path, renamed)
    except:
        #how am I supposed to create converted a filename without these Cyrillic characters ?
        #i think it has something to do with using the translit() function from transliterate library
        continue

print "Done."
```

Or maybe I should change the except part for something like this:

```
except:
    renamed2 = translit(path, 'ru', reversed=True) 
    os.rename(path, renamed2)
```

So...

- how am I supposed to create converted a filename without these cyrilic characters ?

Can someone show me the right way to use [`translit()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate/1.7.6) to create a valid filename for the `os.rename()` method ?

Maybe something like this:

```
print translit(u"Лорем ипсум долор сит амет", 'ru', reversed=True)
# Output: Lorеm ipsum dolor sit amеt
```

But while looping over the files inside the folder...

Comment: If you use Unicode strings for the old and new names, you shouldn't have to transliterate at all.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I think this is what I was looking for, but couldn't implement in my code... I don't know how unicode works.. it's kinda weird for me yet. But it sounds a lot 'easier' to implement than transliterating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

After searching a little more I found the following solution:

1. Changed `folder = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\musics"` to `folder = u"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\musics"`
2. Added the following piece of code to my `except:` part.

**Fix:**

```
except:
    newName = translit(item, 'ru', reversed=True)
    renamed2 = folder  + "\\" + newName
    os.rename(path, renamed2)
```

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from transliterate import translit

folder = u"C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\musics"

for item in os.listdir(folder):

    item2 = item[:]
    path = folder + "\\" + item

    try:
        renamed = folder  + "\\" + item2
        os.rename(path, renamed)

    except:
        newName = translit(item, 'ru', reversed=True)
        renamed2 = folder  + "\\" + newName
        os.rename(path, renamed2)

print "done."
```